# get options data of NSE from Alpha Vantage API

Tags: api, alpha-vantage

Using Alpha Vantage documentation I am able to fetch data of stock listed on NSE (National Stock Exchange of India) like bellow 
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=EMA&symbol=NSE:TCS&interval=weekly&time_period=10&series_type=open&apikey=demo

But I am not able to same for **options**

Is there any way to get data for stock/index options from alpha vantage?

Answer (score 7):

Not at the moment - everything that is currently available is on the documentation page:

https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/

If you don't want to keep any of the data or use it commercially, you can generally download the options data from any online brokerage; for example [tradier](https://documentation.tradier.com/brokerage-api/markets/get-options-strikes)

If you want to keep the data from [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/) and [Intrinio](https://intrinio.com/), both have solid packages for options data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it used to work before, but it's not working anymore for `NSE` data. It works only for `BSE` data now.

It's better to get data from a reliable site.